# How to set multiple transparent images as backgrounds in HTML?

Tags: html, css

Here is the current background:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body style="background: #5d5d5d url(images/tile_dark.png); 
                 border: 20px solid #00c09e; 
                 margin: 0; 
                 padding: 0;">
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to display another image over the green border. How can I make it?

Comment: Should another image be displayed over only the green border?

Comment: Yes. The border right now is only a color. I need it as a color and image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: added **[DEMO in jsFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tcup8m2v/2/)**

You can create a `<div>` like:

```
 <div id="another"></div>
```

with a background image that is positioned on top of the border and make it transparent using css opacity.

sample CSS:

```
#another{
    position: absolute;
    background: url('path/to/image');
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0.5;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't display the background of an element outside of that element. You can try and do a

```
body::after{
   content:'';
   display:block;
   position:absolute;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   background:url(images/yourimage)
 };
```

For multiple images on the same element, separate them by comma like:

```
background: #color1 background:url(path-to-image1) 0px 0px no-repeat, #color2 background:url(path-to-image) 1px 1px repeat-x; /*and so on*/
```

You also can not make the background image transparent, only the background color. If you need the background image to be transparent, change the opacity of the element. For transparent background color user:

```
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5); /*first 3 are color codes -RGB, last one is opacity from 0 to 1*/
```

Comment: Thanks Radu, but I am looking to display an already transparent image over only the green border.

Comment: Then might you have a fiddle example? It would help me help you since, I doubt you have an element that has an image added as a background, wrapped in a border with the background spilling over that border. I think the html skeleton might look different then your example.

Answer (score 0):

Set that background on border-image,
Try CSS [border-image](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp).

EDIT:

```
body {
    background: green;
}
#another{
    background: blue;
    width: 50%;
    border-image: url(http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/space-wallpaper-2-798x350.jpg) 30 30 round;
    border-width: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 200px;
}
```